# How to make imageview scroll along with tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have created a view controller with a ImageView on top and a TableView on the bottom. Ideally I want the whole screen to scroll together when TableView overflows. But actually only the tableview would scroll yet the ImageView will stay where it was. How can I fix it?

Below is my storyboard screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Better add imageview to header of the table view.

Answer (score 0):

just locate imageview above uitableviewcell in tableview hierarchy.